# Using OpenCV to smooth pure black pixels inwards to make a transtition

Tags: python, opencv

I have some python code that is meant to process a depth map to simulate a kind of focal area (pure black). I have all of this working and just need to make a smooth transition  from white to black to make the effect less harsh.

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Load the depth map image
img = cv2.imread("./image-outputs/PXL_20231229_013919393-dpt_beit_large_512.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Create a copy of the image to preserve the original
result_img = img.copy()
copy = img.copy()

# Choose a scaling factor (experiment with values above 1)
min_value = img.min() 
scale_factor = (255 - min_value) / min_value
if scale_factor > 255:
    scale_factor = 255
# Apply the scale_factor to all pixels
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        pixel_value = img[i, j]
        if pixel_value < 127:
            flipped_value = int(pixel_value * scale_factor)
            img[i, j] = flipped_value
        pixel_value = copy[i, j]
        if 50 <= pixel_value <= 80:
           img[i, j] =  0 # Set to black
        else:
           result_img[i, j] = abs(pixel_value)  # Get absolute value



cv2.imwrite("focus-map-flipped-darkest-to-brightest.png", img)
```

I have tried using erode to smooth the image (which just gives me a blurred or black image depending on what I try) and dilating the image by -10 (errors out) Please help!!

Example Image:
[image]

Comment: example PNG file please.

Comment: Yep! Sorry i forgot it. Heres what the code outputs: https://ibb.co/wwP2VLT

Comment: Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. It's hard to know what you are trying to accomplish. Thanks.